# Kotlin replace all matching expression in a string

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a text that I get from database such as this : "Hello world \\n how are you \\n I hope you are fine."

I need to change all the `"\\n"` of a string by `"\n"`. So far I am doing
`string.replace("\\n", "\n", ignoreCase = true)` but it doesn't work as keeps showing the first \ and the returned text is such as this:

"Hello world \ how are you \ I hope you are fine."

What is the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] showing that it only replaces the first occurrence? I wouldn't expect that to be the case.

Comment: Why not call replaceAll on String if that's what you want?

Comment: I misunderstood what whas happening. I wrote above an explanation of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your database text contains `\\n` and not `\\\\n`? What does your code print  when you print the raw text? Is it `\\n` or `\n`?